# Check if a subview is in a view using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subview

How do I test if a subview has already been added to a parent view? If it hasn't been added, I want to add it. Otherwise, I want to remove it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a subview is in a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421298/check-if-a-subview-is-in-a-view) (importantly, that question already has a Swift answer...)

Comment: In response to nhgrif's comment, the answer you linked to (an Obj-C question) was edited (by YOU) the same day you posted the comment. Did it have Swift at 11:45am when this question was posted and was it an adequate answer? If so, why'd you update it?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use the `UIView` method [`isDescendantOfView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/isDescendantOfView:):

```
if mySubview.isDescendant(of: someParentView) {
    mySubview.removeFromSuperview()
} else {
    someParentView.addSubview(mySubview)
}
```

You may also need to surround everything with `if mySubview != nil` depending on your implementation.

Answer (score 26):

This is a much cleaner way to do it:

```
if myView != nil { // Make sure the view exists

        if self.view.subviews.contains(myView) {
            self.myView.removeFromSuperview() // Remove it
        } else {
           // Do Nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's cleaner or not, but it looks like a good alternate method.

Answer (score 11):

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    if let subView = view as? YourNameView {
        subView.removeFromSuperview()
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: this actually removes the first view of that type of views, but not that you probably want

Answer (score 7):

Here we used  two different views. Parent view is the view in which we are searching for descendant view and check wether  added to parent view or not.

```
if parentView.subviews.contains(descendantView) {
   // descendant view added to the parent view.
  }else{
   // descendant view not added to the parent view.
}
```