# How to Check If UITableViewCell Contains UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I am adding subview to `UITableViewCell` i.e

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault` reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Here `_cellBackgroundView` belongs to `UIView`.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:_cellbackground];
```

I want to check by the help of `isDescendantOfView` if it contains `_cellbackground`, but I am getting warning.

```
if (![_cellbackground isDescendantOfView:[cell subviews]]) {
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_cellbackground];

}
else{
    [_cellbackground removeFromSuperview];
}
```

references [Check if a subview is in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421298/check-if-a-subview-is-in-a-view)

Please help

Comment: You say you are getting warning. What does the warning say ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[cell subviews]` return array , but you need to give `UIView` as input parameter for `isDescendantOfView:` method , try like this it will work

```
if (![_cellbackground isDescendantOfView:cell.contentView]) {
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_cellbackground];
}
else {
    [_cellbackground removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[cell subviews]` should be replaced by a object of `UIView`